# Cannot debugging in VS 2012. VS is restarting itself

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have very strange issue.
I created very basic Console Application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The problem is, when I try to put break point on line, whatever you like and run App, VS is hanging on and restarting itself (without break point there is no situation like that).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SafeMode if you are using extensions. This way you can find out if a extension is causing this.

> Devenv.exe /SafeMode

Use Log to write to a logfile.

> Devenv.ex /Log "c:\temp\log.txt"

Comment: Ok Devenv.exe /SafeMode is working for me! I can debug now!
Thank you Ralf!
How set to open Visual Stuido always in SafeMode?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. To always start VS in safemode open the properties of VS and add '/SafeMode' to Target. Although I would remove extensions until VS starts again.

Comment: Problem solved!
I uninstalled .Net Reflector extension and debug is working correctly without SafeMode and other stuff! 
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

try [running Visual Studio with /Log argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) and check activity log to see if any errors are logged.

Comment: Thank You Jarek! Now I know how to check log file for VS!